# SSIS 2016 build with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssis, msbuild

we want to implement automated SSIS build deployment to SSISCatalogDB using Jenkins. As per my research, MSBuild out of box does not support the SSIS build so we need to use some open source code from Codeplex which is not active since last few years. And even with that code, there are so many DLL issue and verison issues, that there is no guarantees that that dll will actually work on build server. 
So my question is, please let me know if there is any third party product (may be red-gate..) which can actually do this.
Please advise, any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only product I know that might do this is [DILM Suite](https://dilmsuite.com/), but I'm not sure whether this has a command line. I'd suggest [contacting the tool's developer,](https://dilmsuite.com/contact-us/) Andy Leonard.